# How to add column to a DataFrame where value is fetched from a map with other column from row as key

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

I'm new to Spark, and trying to figure out how I can add a column to a DataFrame where its value is fetched from a HashMap, where the key is another value on the same row which where the value is being set.

For example, I have a map defined as follows:

```
var myMap: Map<Integer,Integer> = generateMap();
```

I want to add a new column to my DataFrame where its value is fetched from this map, with the key a current column value. A solution might look like this:

```
val newDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", lit(myMap.get(col("EXISTING_COLUMN"))))
```

My issue with this code is that using the col function doesn't return a type of Int, like the keys in my HashMap.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dataframe from the map. Then do a join operation. It should be faster and can be reused.

A UDF (user-defined function) can also be used but they are black boxes to Catalyst, so I would be prudent in using them. Depending on where the content of the map is, it may also be complicated to pass it to a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

As of the next version of [Kotlin API for Apache Spark](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spark-api) you will be able to simply create a udf which will be usable in almost this way.

```kotlin
val mapUDF by udf { input: Int -> myMap[input] }
dataFrame.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", mapUDF(col("EXISTING_COLUMN")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UDF.

```
val mapUDF = udf((i:Int)=>myMap.getOrElse(i,0))
val newDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", mapUDF(col("EXISTING_COLUMN")))
```